# PHP JSON Parser v.s. Javascript JSON Parser

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have an array via json_encode of PHP serialize:

```
json_encode(array('pattern' => '^(?:/?site/(?[\w\-]+))?(?:/?intl/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\-[a-z]{2})?)/?)?(/?(?.*))'));
// output json: {"pattern":"^(?:\/?site\/(?[\\w\\-]+))?(?:\/?intl\/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\\-[a-z]{2})?)\/?)?(\/?(?.*))"}
```

I tried to decode in Javascript:

```
JSON.parse('{"pattern":"^(?:\/?site\/(?[\\w\\-]+))?(?:\/?intl\/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\\-[a-z]{2})?)\/?)?(\/?(?.*))"}');
```

Then I don't understand why do I get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token w" ??
Is PHP and Javascript JSON parser difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you're using JSON.parse() and enclosing your JSON string in single quotes.

So your escaped regex string gets unescaped in the interpretation of the outer string-literal (single-quoted), and then gets mixed up in the interpretation of the value of the string `pattern` (double-quoted), ultimately causing JavaScript to choke trying to decipher "\w".

The following example, mimicking PHP rendering the JSON verbatim to a declaration, works fine in a JS console:

```
var json = {"pattern":"^(?:\/?site\/(?[\\w\\-]+))?(?:\/?intl\/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\\-[a-z]{2})?)\/?)?(\/?(?.*))"}
```

If you want to use JSON.parse, you have to first double-escape your JSON string in PHP

```
$json = json_encode(array('pattern' => '^(?:/?site/(?[\w\-]+))?(?:/?intl/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\-[a-z]{2})?)/?)?(/?(?.*))'));
$json = str_replace('\', '\\', $json);
// output json: {"pattern":"^(?:\\/?site\\/(?[\\\\w\\\\-]+))?(?:\\/?intl\\/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\\\\-[a-z]{2})?)\\/?)?(\\/?(?.*))"}
```

Then, in JS:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"pattern":"^(?:\\/?site\\/(?[\\\\w\\\\-]+))?(?:\\/?intl\\/(?[a-z]{2}(?:\\\\-[a-z]{2})?)\\/?)?(\\/?(?.*))"}')
```

Comment: It's important to note that this is only necessary because he's typing the JSON as a literal into the JS program. It's not necessary if the JSON is being passed over the network and being processed by the JS that way.